# Chrome won't load css?

Tags: html, css

I am a complete beginner learning HTML and CSS. I am trying to link a css document to my html, but am having no success. The css file is in the same folder as the html. The html loads perfectly, but won't access the css. Can anyone help?

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Practice</title>
  <link rel=“stylesheet” type=“text/css” href=“styles.css” />
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>XXXX</h1>
  <h3>YYYYYYYY</h3>
  <p>ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ</p>
 </body>
</html>
```

Is there something wrong with my code, or is it how my computer won't access the files? I am using MacOS Sierra, and TextEdit to create .html and .css files.

Comment: What is ” ? Use "

Comment: Are you using curly quotes in your HTML file or is that a copy-paste artefact?

Comment: That is just what came up when I typed ' " ' in text edit. Is it a matter of font, or a different character? It looks curly in the text document as well. How can I get the straight quotes?

Comment: TextEdit is a word processor. You should never use a word processor to write source code. Try TextMate or another [source code editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code_editor).

Comment: Search for "MacOS disable smart quotes"

Comment: You want to enclose attribute values in QUOTATION MARK <U+0022> characters; your code has LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK <U+201C> and RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK <U+201D>, which do not have any special meaning in HTML. Get a proper text editor.

Comment: Thank you all! Fixing the quotes worked, and looking into a better text editor.

Comment: @Chuck — You can't go far wrong with VS Code. Free, open source, powerful, cross-platform, and [massively popular](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2018/12/12/rise-of-vs-code.aspx).

Comment: I have experienced this happening with me when I copy code form slack and it has double quotes in it. Especially when a sender doesn't send the code as snippet but sends as a message. Try to be more careful while copying code like that.

Answer (score -1):

Your HTML should be:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Practice</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
 </head>

 <body>
  <h1>XXXX</h1>
  <h3>YYYYYYYY</h3>
  <p>ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ</p>
 </body>
</html>
```

Create a file called styles.css in the same directory with some CSS in it.

Like:

```
h1 { 
  display: block;
  font-size: 2em;
  margin-top: 0.67em;
  margin-bottom: 0.67em;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  color:pink
}
```

Comment: That did that already

Comment: @Quentin please try it again, I edited my answer.

Comment: "And your HTML should be" — That reads like a game of spot-the-difference, not an answer. You should delete this. The solution was identified in comments before you posted the answer, and closed as a duplicate before you came close to identifying the problem.

Comment: @Chuck You could've just copy pasted this code and ran it as it, but it works for me as is (the updated one).